# Не понимаю почему не работает вывод массива в Java

Tags: java

Пишу программу сортировки массива:

```
int[] myArray = {5, 7, 2, 8, 1, 0, 3};
int max = 0;
int l = myArray.length;
int index =0;
int temp = 0;
while (l>=0){
    for (int i=0;i<l;i++){
        if(max<=myArray[i]){
            max=myArray[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    temp = myArray[(l - 1)];
    myArray[index] = temp;
    myArray[(l - 1)] = max;
    String s = " Iteration - " + l + " MAX INDEX = " + index + " temp = " + temp + " MAX = " + max;
    System.out.println(s);
    index = 0;
    max = 0;
    l = l-1;
}
for (int v : myArray){
    System.out.print(v);
}
```

Выводит только процесс сортировки, а отсортированный массив не выводит

```
 Iteration - 7 MAX INDEX = 3 temp = 3 MAX = 8
 Iteration - 6 MAX INDEX = 1 temp = 0 MAX = 7
 Iteration - 5 MAX INDEX = 0 temp = 1 MAX = 5
 Iteration - 4 MAX INDEX = 3 temp = 3 MAX = 3
 Iteration - 3 MAX INDEX = 2 temp = 2 MAX = 2
 Iteration - 2 MAX INDEX = 0 temp = 0 MAX = 1
 Iteration - 1 MAX INDEX = 0 temp = 0 MAX = 0
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ideone.com/RBjVNj

Твой код падает при обращении к элементу массива с индексом `-1`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>       at Ideone.main(Main.java:24)

```
temp = myArray[(l - 1)];
```

Когда исправишь эту ошибку, вывод массива будет работать почти нормально.
Почти заключается в отсутствии пробелов между числами.

---

Возможно, ошибка в условии цикла while и его нужно изменить на такое:

```
while (l>0){
```

http://ideone.com/CbdmLl

Но гарантировать не могу, разбираться с алгоритмом сортировки мне лень.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за помощь, исправил условие в цикле while
и поправил вывод результат, с пробелами

```
int[] myArray = {5, 7, 2, 8, 1, 0, 3,6};
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    for (int v : myArray){
        System.out.print(v + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    int max = 0;
    int l = myArray.length;
    int index =0;
    int temp = 0;
    while (l>0){
        for (int i=0;i<l;i++){
            if(max<=myArray[i]){
                max=myArray[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        temp = myArray[(l - 1)];
        myArray[index] = temp;
        myArray[(l - 1)] = max;
        index = 0;
        max = 0;
        l = l-1;
    }
    System.out.print("Result: ");
    for (int v : myArray){
        System.out.print(v + " ");
    }
```